# MFMailComposeViewController get default user email "from" mail

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I couldn't seem to find anywhere where people specifically say you cant get the default user mail from the MFMailComposeViewController. So I just create this thread to make sure.

Comment: No I dont want to read existing mails. I want to get the default user email. For instance jlkl@me.com, from the MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: Okay in that case I misread your question. Yes, it is possible to send from the existing mail id. In fact that is how it works. But you cant access it. That will be prepopulated on the screen for the user.

Comment: So my only way is to prompt the user for the email... Not that nice a way to do it...

Comment: Can you please tell what exactly is your requirement in this case? Normally, what you can do is to show the `MFMailComposeViewController` and let the user fill rest of the things. They can choose from which Id they can send the mail. Rest of the things can be filled via coding.

Comment: I need the mail to send it in the mail as an url scheme. From that url scheme, the recipient will be able to press it and do some actions, after those actions, an MFMailComposeViewController will pop up and autofill the "to" field.

Comment: Yes, autofilling "To" field, if you already have the mail id is possible. However retrieving user's default mail id is not possible. For example, if you want user to send the mail to your id, you can put that as "TO" field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is no way to get the "From" id in `MFMailComposeViewController`. You can only set the "To" and "Cc" fields. This is understandable in cases where the "From" mail id you are planning to set is not configured in the device.

The device will auto fill the from field with the default mail id of the user. User can switch between different ids once the `MFMailComposeViewController` is presented.